# How to creat a 'remove item' button in simple cart?

Tags: javascript, paypal, simplecart

Ok so I have simple cart installed ( simple javascript cart that works in conjunction with payapl)

I had someone implement simple cart, but they are no longer available.

I need a way to remove the items from my cart.

Right now, if I input a value of '0' then the items are removed, but this may not be evident to my users.

Is it possible to make a little 'remove item link per item?

please visit:

http://www.bodesi.com/product/tiling/small-subway-mosaic/15x48x6/Hand-Painted/SMTI026/SMTI026.html#ad-image-0

please add an item, and see the cart in the top right hand corner.

thanks in advance and hope I have been clear! let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a view cart button, and then from there the buyer can remove items from the cart.  You could use the code for the view cart button, and use a different button image so that it is clear that they can click the button to view the cart or to remove items.  Once they click the button, it would show the buyer all of their items in the cart, and the could remove them as needed from there.

Comment: Yea I have something like that I just don't know how to create the actual remove from cart button. any idea?

Comment: There isn't any code that PayPal generates to do this.  The items are added to cart using cookies.  You may want to create your own cart, this way you would have control over it.  Then you would just pass the details over to PayPal using the cart upload command when the buyer is ready to checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still at this or not but there is a very simple solution built into simplecartjs.

Empty Entire Cart: `<a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_empty"></a>`

Remove single Items: `<a class="simpleCart_remove" href="javascript:;">Whatever Text You want</a>`

Also noticed that you don't have any onscreen alert letting the user know that things have been added to the cart after they select ADD TO CART (I clicked about 3 times before I realized it was adding it). :)

For this, you use another simple approach called afteradd from simplecartjs:

```
    simpleCart.bind( "afterAdd" , function(){
    $('.add-cart-msg').hide()
                      .addClass('success')
                      .html('Added to cart successfully!')
                      .fadeIn(300)
                      .delay(3000)
                      .fadeOut(1300);

    });
```

Then all you need is something with `class="add-cart-msg"` next to the ADD TO CART button. It will fade in, sit there for about 3 seconds, then fade out.

I hope you find this helpful.

Here is some very handy reference material: [Simplecartjs Documentation](http://simplecartjs.org/documentation)